# Is it possible share an object between to WCF services that are on different sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, session-variables

I'm have been googling and searching the internet to see if it possible to share objects between two WCF services on different sites.
For example: 
I have one service on http//site1/service1.svc and another service on http://site2/service2.svc, when a user access

Is it possible if I make a call to service1.svc and store an object in the context/session, use this same object in service2.svc?

I was reading about InstanceContextSharing, could this be the way to what I want?

Comment: why don't you just pass the information as a SOAP message to your second service?

Comment: do u have control of both ends

Comment: @Musab , yes I do have control on both ends, but I wouldn't want to call all services to "force a start" of a session on all of them, but just call one service and this one would propagate this session data to all others services.
When I call a different service it will have this same "session data". I hope that I could explain what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for out-of-proc state sharing. Consider SOSS (http://static.scaleoutsoftware.com/docs/soss_help/content/index.html#_introduction) or Redis (https://redis.io/)caching.

If these solution are way too large for your problem, Here are couple of more alternatives

1. you can consider having duplex channel,
2. Create a Database table that helps service2 get to the object created by service1. you will have to devise a method so that Service2 can identify the database record correctly